# what is the below code giving garbage characters as output for Caesar Cipher Encryption algorithm?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int count=0;
int main(){
    int n; 
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    char *s = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
    scanf(" %s",s);
    int length=strlen(s);
    char array[length+1];
    int k; 
    scanf(" %d",&k);
    while(*s!='\0')
        {

        char a= *s + k;
        if(a>90 && *s<=90)
            {
            a=65+(k-1);
            array[count]=a;
        }
        else if(a>122 && *s<=122)
            {
            a=97+(k-1);
            array[count]=a;
        }
        else if (a >=0 && a<=64)
            {
            array[count]=a;
        }
       else if(a>=123 && a<=126)
           {
           array[count]=a;
       }

        count++;
        s++;


    }
    array[count+1]='\0';
    printf("%s",array);
    return 0;
}
```

In the below code ,Each unencrypted letter is replaced with the letter occurring  'k' spaces after it when listed alphabetically. Think of the alphabet as being both case-sensitive and circular; if 'k' rotates past the end of the alphabet, it loops back to the beginning (i.e.: the letter after 'z' is 'a' , and the letter after 'Z' is 'A' ).

I am unable to get where I am going wrong ,it is printing null for every possible input sequence of letters .The special symbols don't change in the encrypted string .

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: ...especially since you never included `<stdlib.h>`, mandatory for proper usage of `malloc`. And related, your `array[]` is undersized. You leave no space for the terminator.

Comment: Even if I include it , it is not working as desired ,no changes in output.

Comment: Since you create a static-, fixed-size buffer that does not need to survive the function returning, it would be much easier and cleaner to declare it as an *array*: `char s[10240];`.  10 KB is unlikely to be too much for the stack.

Comment: On the other hand, just because you make the buffer big does not mean it is safe from being overrun.  Specify a suitable field width in your `scanf()` format to ensure that that does not happen.

Comment: strlen gives the entire length of the string including null character and even if I declare array size as length+1 , still I am not getting desired output .

Comment: I have edited the code , please see still I am getting some garbage characters .

Comment: `strlen` does not include the NULL character in its returned length

Comment: Please do not delete questions which people are trying to answer, and then make a bunch of corrections before re-enabling. And do not use "magic numbers" in the code. if `122` means anything in context, it is `'z'`.

Comment: Time to study encodings, especially character encodings.

Comment: I suspect the first problem is in that clusterf in between `main` and your `while` loop. Start by hardcoding the word you want to encode as well as the `k` value and work backwards from there. What is `n`? Why is `count` outside of `main`?

Answer (score 0):

```
k = 2; //<== random input
while (*s != '\0')
{
    printf("count %d\n", count);
    char a = *(s + k);
    ...
}
```

This loop goes to the end of the string `s`, and `char a` tries to extract the character which is `k` positions after the current index.

So when you are at the end of the string, `*(s + k)` is out of bound. I recommend rewriting the code as follows:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (i + k == length) break;
    if (i + k < 0) break; //assuming k can be negative
    char a = s[i + k];
    ...
}
```

This way `i+k` is always a valid index between `0` and `length`.

Another problem is here:

```
if (a>90 && *s <= 90)
{
    a = (char)(65 + (k - 1));
    array[count] = a;
}
else if (a>122 && *s <= 122)
{
    a = (char)(97 + (k - 1));
    array[count] = a;
}
else if (a >= 0 && a <= 64)
{
    array[count] = a;
}
else if (a >= 123 && a <= 126)
{
    array[count] = a;
}
count++;
```

There is no guarantee that at least of these conditions is met. In fact it is likely that all of the conditions are false. So what happens is that `array[0]` remains uninitialized, but `count` is still incremented, therefore `array` contains garbage at the end. It should be changed so that `count` is incremented only if `array[count]` is set.

For Caesar encryption you want to shift the characters to left or right. You can do this by use `%` operator.

```
strcpy(s, "ABCDEFGZ");
int length = strlen(s);
char *array = malloc(length + 1);
int shift = 2;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    char c = s[i];
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + shift) % 26;
    array[i] = c;
}
array[i] = 0;
```

Note when `'Z'` is shifted to the right, the `%` operator makes sure it get back in to range between `'A'` to `'Z'`

The above function is not complete, it won't work for lower case letters, that's for your homework...